# How to display multi line data stored in database

Tags: php, html

I am storing a data like this

“Com­mu­ni­ca­tion is often the har­dest part of leadership.”

gaping­void crea­tes ideas and ima­ges SPECIFICALLY for lea­ders: uni­que and crea­tive pre­sen­ta­tion decks, ani­ma­tions and other visual props that help deli­ver mes­sa­ges in unex­pec­ted, memo­ra­ble and more mea­ning­ful ways.
These visuals are not only desig­ned to delight and disarm your audience, they’re desig­ned make you and your mes­sage sing, win­ning your audience over, making them want to talk about you and your vision for months to come.

i have used nl2br to retrive the data from database  it's displaying the data as i entered bt the issue is observe these examples   they’re  and memo-­ra­-ble  it is displaying as they?re and memo?ra?ble  please help in rectifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a meta charset tag in html header and sent it to `utf-8`

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and run this before running your query

```
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //am assuming you are using mysqli

<?php echo nl2br($row_show_shared_info["description"]);?>
```

it should fix it.

Comment: can you post the code, how you are displaying it from db

Comment: <p><?php echo nl2br($row_show_shared_info["description"]);?></p>

Comment: �Communication is often the hardest part of leadership.�

gaping void creates ideas and images SPECIFICALLY for leaders: unique and creative presentation decks, animations and other visual props that help deliver messages in unexpected, memorable and more meaningful ways.
These visuals are not only designed to delight and disarm your audience, they�re desig�ned make you and your message sing, winning your audience over, making them want to talk about you and your vision for months to come.

Comment: before communication ? is start of "  and ? after leadership is end of "   ? at they?re is to be printed as they're    and desig?ned  as desig-ned.

Comment: and one more thing can i restrcit it to print just 4 lines of the data and remaining after clicking on the data i want to display it in other form.

Comment: you should do it using jquery, don't run one more query for same thing, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270227/how-to-hide-show-more-text-within-a-certain-length-like-youtube)