# bootstrap card text showing limit

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

i want to set a limit in my card-text to like 200 words, so it does not display the whole text in the card box field.
Is there a way to do that without script? Or when there is only a solution with script, how would you implement that in my code?
Any help would be nice, thank you!

[image: posts]

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) { $i = 0; // Ein Zähler um zusehen, wann eine neue Reihe erstellt werden soll $beitrag .= "

<div class='album py-5 bg-light'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>"; while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { $beitrag_id = $row['beitrag_id']; $titel = $row['titel']; $miete = $row['miete']; $einkauf = $row['einkauf']; $freizeit = $row['freizeit']; $sonstiges = $row['sonstiges']; $g_kosten = $row['g_kosten']; $p_text
      = $row['p_text']; $beitrag .= "

      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class='card mb-4 box-shadow'>
          <div class='card-header'>
            <a href='siehe_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'>
              <h4 class='my-0 font-weight-normal'>$titel</h4>
            </a>
            <h4 class='my-0 font-weight-normal'>$g_kosten&euro;</h4>
          </div>
          <div class='card-body'>
            <p class='card-text'>$p_text</p>
            <div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
            </div>
          </div>"; if(isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] == 1) { //Buttons loeschen und bearbeiten anzeigen, falls es ein angemeldeter Nutzer ist $beitrag .= "
          <div class='btn-group'>
            <a href='loeschen_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'>
              <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger'>Loeschen</button>
              <a href='bearbeiten_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Bearbeiten</button>
          </div>"; } $beitrag .= " </div>
      </div>"; $i++; if($i % 3 == 0) { // Drei Ergebnisse in der div -> Starte eine neue $beitrag .= "
    </div>
  </div>
</div>"; $beitrag .= "

<div class='album py-5 bg-light'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>"; } } if(($i - 1) % 3 != 0) { // An der letzten Schleife schließen $beitrag .= "
    </div>
  </div>
</div>"; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270227/how-to-hide-show-more-text-within-a-certain-length-like-youtube