# Unable to submit form after copying from one place to another

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm shifting form `#cart_form` from right column to left column after a button is hit.

And the code for that is:

```
$('#left_col').html($('#cart_form').html());
```

But I cannot submit it. I wondered if the code above properly copied all tags, right from `<form>` to `</form>`

I checked if `form` element exists, like this:

```
if ($('form').length == 0) {
   alert("no");
}
```

And it doesn't alert 'no' meaning it exist. The markup for my form is,

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="cart_form">
<table class='header_tbl' style="background:none !important;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Amount(RM)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
.........................
CONTENT APPENDED BY JQueRY
........................
```

This button initiates the submission:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='receipt' onclick='print_me()' value='PRINT RECEIPT'/>
```

And this is how it submit if cart is not empty.

```
function print_me(){
     var ele = $(".header_tbl tbody tr").children().length;

     if(ele > 0)
     {
$("#cart_form").submit(function(){
                var data = {
                  "action": "test"
                };
                data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  url: "submit_cart.php",
                  data: data,
                  success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);
                   }
                  });
               });


}else
     {
       alert("Your cart is empty.");
     }
}
```

Comment: Moving elements this way you loose event handlers. Check this question and answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716986/swap-2-html-elements-and-preserve-event-listeners-on-them

Comment: He is not loosing his event handler because the onclick event is used directly on the button

Comment: Agree. He is copying only inner html. That is why no form tag there. He should grab outer html: $('#cart_form')[0].outerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("#yourform").html() is copying what is inside your form tag without your form tag.

Try to put your form into a div

```
<div id="divID">
<form action="#" method="POST" id="cart_form">
<table class='header_tbl' style="background:none !important;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Amount(RM)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</form>
</div>
```

and then do that :

```
$('#left_col').html( $("#divID").html() );
```

Comment: doesn't submit still

Comment: Try to inspect your html code to see if the tag form is copied.. I think that when you do $("#yourform").html() it is copying what is inside your form tag

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459398/jquery-get-html-of-container-including-the-container-itself

Comment: I guess the same ..but how do I check if for tag exist?

Comment: If you are on google chrome right click on your page et select the last option inspect element

Comment: as inspected, I found the <form> and </form> are missing. The  markup starts and end with table.

Comment: I understand that form is not coppied, I reffered to the links you provided to copy the parent() but doesn't work

Comment: I think I'm doing it wrong way..var x = $('#cart_form')[0].outerHTML; $('#left_col').html(x);

Comment: well it seam to be fine...  or you could try to add your form into a div... and give an id to this div. `$("#yourdiv").html()` and then you would have your form. You will have `$('#left_col').html( $("#yourdiv").html() );`

Comment: still same, it doesn't shift anything to the new destination

Comment: i have edited my last comment check it... does it works?

Comment: I tried it just now, exactly the same, but still I see blank in the new destination. I just wonder why!

Comment: I did this   alert($("#form_here").html()); and the entire form is displayed just that it doesn't moving to the new destination?

Comment: can i see your left_col div

Comment: <div class='small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns' id='left_col'>
       <div class="container">..content here...........</div></div>

Comment: I tried this too:  $('#left_col .container').html( $("#form_here").html() );

Comment: well i don't know sorry .. if you try to add all your form to this div in your code does everything is shown fine?

Comment: i got it working, I added  <form action="#" method="POST" id="cart_form2"> </form> in the left_col and shifted the div into this , and can submit now

Answer (score 1):

Try  `$('#left_col').html( $('#cart_form')[0].outerHTML )`

Comment: doesn't append to the new destination

Comment: Are you sure you  have that form on the page  before moving it to the left? Can you run the `if ($('#cart_form').length == 0) {` check before move?

Comment: yes I have the form element, ran the ($('form').length == 0) {