# In React js, how to swap a two select component values onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two select components right & left side with different values consider A->right side & B->left side, **In a button click function I need to swap a A -> select component to Left and B-> select component to right**. How to achieve this in react js.

```
function SelectComponentA({
<select name="Country" id="Country">
  <option value="France">France</option>
  <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
)}
export SelectComponentA


function SelectComponentB({
<select name="Segment" id="Segment">
  <option value="Segment 1">Segment 1</option>
  <option value="Segment 2">Segment 2</option>
</select>

export SelectComponentB
```

I tried using a UseState

const [dropDownSwap, setSwap] = useState(true)

```
  function swapDropDownComponents() {
    setSwap(!dropDownSwap)
  }

 {dropDownSwap ? SelectComponentA : SelectComponentB}

<button type="button" Onclick={SwapSelectComponent}>Swap</button>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the positions of two HTML elements? Or you want the options in the select components to be swapped?

Comment: I want to change the position and their respective values

Comment: If you want to change positions - Element Left will be on Right and Element Right will now be on the left. What does changing values mean? Can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: Exactly that I'm looking for, changing the position to right to left and left to right.

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716986/swap-two-html-elements-and-preserve-event-listeners-on-them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to swap the two components on button click then you need to define the structure in the condition rendering. With the help of useState toggle the boolean value to set the specific structure. This is demonstrated by the following code.`

```
const [swap, setSwap] = useState(false)

const Select1 = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <label for="cars">Select Component A</label>
            <select name="Country" id="Country">
                <option value="France">France</option>
                <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
            </select>
        </>
    )
}
const Select2 = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <label for="cars">Select Component B</label>
            <select name="Segment" id="Segment">
                <option value="Segment 1">Segment 1</option>
                <option value="Segment 2">Segment 2</option>
            </select>
        </>
    )
}


return (
    <div>
        {swap ? <div> <Select1 /><Select2 /> </div> : <div> <Select2 /><Select1 /> </div>}
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>setSwap(!swap)}>Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
)`
```