# How can i fix this problem with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**i want to put third elememt to second place but i cant **

```js
const par = document.getElementsByClassName('menu' ),
      chil = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
        console.log(par, chil);
        par.insertBefore(chil[2] , chil[1])
```

```html
 <nav>
       <ul class="menu">
         <li class="menu-item">Первый пункт</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Третий пункт</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Второй пункт</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Четвертый пункт</li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to swap DOM child nodes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732624/how-to-swap-dom-child-nodes-in-javascript)

Comment: `"message": "TypeError: par.insertBefore is not a function",`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not an element, it's a collection of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName() returns HTMLCollection rather than dom element,

you should write this: `const par = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0]`