# How to append Span to input field dynamically using native javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 5 input box in my page. I want to check if any field is blank, i will show the error message using a span tag appending to that input field.

Here is my code:

```
function validateForm() {   
// Declare all the local variable
var inputElements, inputId, inputType, i, inputLength, inputNode;

// Get all the input tags
inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 

for(i = 0, inputLength = inputElements.length; i < inputLength; i++) {
    inputId = inputElements[i].id; // Get the input field ID
    inputType = inputElements[i].type; // Get the input field type

    // We will ONLY look for input[type=text]
    if(inputType === "text") {
        inputNode = document.getElementById(inputId);
        if(inputNode.value === "") {
            var spanTag = document.createElement("span"); 
            spanTag.innerHTML = inputFieldBlankErrorMessage;
            console.log(inputNode.appendChild(spanTag));
        }
    }       
}
return false; // Do Nothing
```

}

This is what i am getting 
[image]

It should append after the input tag. I am getting a weird  tag which i don't need. Please help!!!

Comment: "is not working" is not an error description; please set up a test case or describe what is not working *after* debugging the JS using your browsers tools (e.g. the console output)

Comment: FYI, you don't need to get the `.id` of the element just to turn around and fetch it by its id. Just use the element from the collection.

Comment: Is `<input><span/></input>` even valid?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of what i am getting...I am expecting <input /><span>some text here<span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `.appendChild()` anything to an `input` node, since an `input` can have no descendants.

Instead, you should insert the new node after it, or something similar.

```
inputNode.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag, inputNode.nextSibling);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/hMBHT/

Comment: Actually he wants an `insertAfter`. As it doesn't exists natively you should create one (using `parentNode.appendChild()` if last element) or just send him the jQuery code if he have jQuery on the page.

Comment: @DiegoNunes: This will do an insert after. I originally excluded the `.nextSibling` by mistake. The `.insertBefore()` method will behave like `.appendChild()` if there's no `.nextSibling` *(in other words, if you don't pass an element as the second argument, it'll just do an `.appendChild()`)*.

Comment: there is the possibility of the input being the lastChild and there will be no `nextSibling`.

Comment: @DiegoNunes: Just updated my previous comment to explain. ;-)

Comment: @DiegoNunes - that shouldn't be a problem, per here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library

Comment: Just a quick question, how do i remove the span after passing the validation?

Comment: @DeepakRanjanJena: `inputNode.parentNode.removeChild(inputNode.nextSibling)`. Though you should really consider simply having the `span` elements in place when the page loads, but give them a class and style them with `span.hidden { display: none; }` in your CSS. Then it's just a matter of updating the text content of each one and showing/hiding them.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put you are not supposed to append any elements to input elements.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" name="bla"/>
  <span class="error">This field can't be blank!</span>
</div>
```

So you need to insert the span before or after the input element.
[Here is an answer that shows you how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that you are trying to append the span as a **child** of the input, not a sibling (which, I believe, is what you really want).

I can't to be sure without seeing your actual HTML, because I don't know how your inputs are situated in the DOM, but if they have separate parent elements, then you would replace:

```
inputNode.appendChild(spanTag);
```

. . . with

```
inputNode.parentNode.appendChild(spanTag);
```

**Edit:** FYI, the code that squint gave below (`inputNode.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag, inputNode.nextSibling);`) would be how you could do it if all of the inputs are under the same parent element.  It all depends on how the DOM structure is set up.

Comment: This will add the spanTag as the last element of the parent's children list. An `insertAfter` code is what he is looking for.

Comment: @DiegoNunes - Yeah, that's what I was trying to say . . . it will work if the each input is under it's own parent.  Without the HTML to show the structure, it's hard to tell how to approach it.  Just offering up a possibility, if that's how his HTML is set up.