# jQuery to Pure javaScript Questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing with JavaScript and have set myself the task of converting some jQuery I wrote last night to pure JavaScript. I've come across a few questions I was wondering if someone cold help me with.

- is `$(this)` a jQuery object, and not used in pure JavaScript (is `this.something` the same)?
- can you easily do something like `.after()` in pure JavaScript or is it just silly?

I'm converting this in to pure JavaScript at the moment..

```
$('.list li').each(function(i) {
    if( ( i + 1 ) % numRow == 0 )
    {
         $(this).after( "<div class='rowBreak'></div>" );
    }
});
```

so far I have this:

```
var totalThumbs = $('.list li').length;

for ( var i = 0; i < totalThumbs; i++ ) {
    if( ( i + 1 ) % numRow == 0 )
    {
        $(this).after( "<div class='rowBreak'></div>" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `totalThumbs` coming from? Is there an array or collection of some sort associated with it?

Comment: The `$` is the jquery object. In pure javascript there is no `$` (unless you define it).

Comment: `$()` is jQuery. `this` gets context in `each` but you don't have that context in `for` loop

Comment: Why don't you check out the jQuery source code and see how these constructs are implemented?  jQuery *is* JavaScript after all...

Comment: `this` is available though, but it has to reference something :) As you've written it there is no `this`available (not in normal js or jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is `$(this)` a jQuery object, and not used in pure JavaScript (is `this.something` the same)?

Yes, `$(this)` is a jQuery object, this allows the use of jQuery methods on whatever is currently represented by `this` (Wrapped in jQuery). This is not the same as `this`, nor is it used in plain JavaScript.

```
`this.something`
```

Is an attempt to access the `something` property, or attribute, of a plain DOM node, a property which you'd have to define yourself.

> can you easily do something like `.after()` in pure JavaScript or is it just silly?

If it was 'just silly' the jQuery team probably wouldn't have bothered to implement it. It can, however, be (relatively) easily implemented as a method of an HTMLElement in plain JavaScript (or as a function, if you'd prefer).

```
HTMLElement.prototype.after = function(newNode){
    // 'this' refers to the DOM node to which this method is chained:
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, this.nextSibling);
}

var aNewNode = document.createElement('div'),
    nodeToActOn = document.getElementById('demo');
aNewNode.innerHTML = '<p>Some text in a paragraph of a newly-created node.</p>';

nodeToActOn.after(aNewNode);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vR7u5/).

References:

- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).
- [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling).

Answer (score 2):

Some but not all functions exist both in jQuery and pure JS.

`after` is not not one of them.

Here is a sample of how to do it without jQuery

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
```

(source: [How to do insert After() in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library))

Converting your code to pure JS would be something like (note I don't really know why you would be inserting a `div` after a `li`, so I changed it to add a class):

```
var lists = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
for (var i = 0, l = lists.length; i < l; i++) {
    var items = lists[i].getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var ii = 0, ll = items.length; ii < ll; ii++) {
        if ((ii + 1) % 2 == 0) {
            items[ii].classList.add('row-break');
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tB3v6/1/

Comment: For Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library

Comment: so the $(this) would be replaced with 'this' and passed through as the referenceNode in to the function and the newNode would be the html markup "<div class='rowBreak'></div>"?

Comment: @pixeltooth I added an example conversion to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

insertAdjacentHTML() parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position.

if you are insert HTML string after an element i thingk insertAdjacentHTML is simple

```
// <div id="one">one</div> 
var d1 = document.getElementById('one'); 
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="two">two</div>');

// At this point, the new structure is:
// <div id="one">one</div><div id="two">two</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML