# HTML multiple field selection in option tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a code which will display two option tag like:

```
<select id="test1" id="name" onchange="checkField()">
    <option>----</option>
<option>Selected A Group</option>
<option>Selected B Group</option>
</select>
<div id="optional">Please select!</div>
```

My aim is that when a user selects option A then depending on that option E should come down **not option B,C,D.**  On the other hand if user selects option B then other set of option like **option X should come down.** Finally when user has selected all the option a **submit button should pop up and redirect to  URL on click event only.** Definitely there will be conditions as like switch case in c language so what should come in HTML ??

This goes on! This is a C example of my query. What is it in HTML using option tag only? 
Even in JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/3GkrX

JS

```
function checkField(){
var temp = document.getElementById('test1').value;

    switch(temp){

        case "Selected A Group":
            document.getElementById("optional").innerHTML="<select name='optionalA'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>";
            break;
        case "Selected B Group":
            document.getElementById("optional").innerHTML="<select name='optionalB'><option>3</option><option>4</option></select>";
            break
            default:
                document.getElementById("optional").innerHTML="Please select!";
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: @popnoodles Please go through this -> jsfiddle.net/3GkrX As you can see in the fiddle after selecting GROUP A then other options are continued. I want that to continue for any number of selection Also at last iteration it should display a SUBMIT button that will navigate to a specific URL depending upon options selected previously In short Submit button "should not navigate to only a SINGLE URL ALL THE TIME instead it should depend on choices that user would make""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a switch statement, but that's not the best way to do it. What I'd suggest is making the following function your event handler for the `change` event. You'll also need to run it on window load, to initialise it.

```
function updateSel() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
    var hidden = sel.getElementsByClassName('hidden');
    for (var i=0;i<hidden.length;i++) {
        var showIt = sel.value == hidden[i].dataset.toggle || sel.selectedOptions[0] == hidden[i];
        hidden[i].style.display = showIt ? 'inline' : 'none';
    }
}
```

With this HTML code for your options:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="A" selected="selected">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E" class="hidden" data-toggle="A">E</option>
    <option value="X" class="hidden" data-toggle="B">X</option>
</select>
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DMS7Z/)** is a demo of this code.

What this does is the following: Everytime the value of the `select` is changed, it checks if the `option` tags with `class="hidden"` are supposed to be visible. It's supposed to be visible when it's selected, or when the option that makes it show (which is stored in its [data-toggle attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)) is selected.

#### `switch` method

If you would want to do this with a switch statement, you'd have to define which element to show, and then hide all others. That would look like this:

```
function updateSel() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
    var hidden = sel.getElementsByClassName('hidden');
    var doShow;
    switch (sel.value) {
        case: 'A': case 'E':
            doShow = hidden['toggle-A'];
            break;
        case: 'B': case 'X':
            doShow = hidden['toggle-B'];
            break;
    }
    for (var i=0;i<hidden.length;i++) {
        list[i].style.display = hidden[i] == doShow?'inline':'none';
    }
}
```

For this to work you'd have to change the `data-toggle` attribute to an `id` though, like this:

```
<option value="E" class="hidden" id="toggle-A">E</option>
```

**[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5ES8/)** shows how that'd work. It basically does the same thing, but instead of letting the script find the tag that needs to be shown all by itself, you have to define each one seperately in your switch statement. I'd suggest using the medhod above without switch statement, but if you want to be able to make for example the X `<option>` show if the user selects *either* B or C, then the switch method is probably better. In that case, you can simply add another `case 'C':` and then it'll show when the user selects C too. If you only need to show 1 specific option at a time (which it seemed like in your question), the first method is much easier to set up.

## New method

In response to your comments, I've made another script that does what you requested:

**[here](http://jsfiddle.net/3GkrX/2/)** is the script's demo.

And the code itself:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" id="questionForm">
    <select name="Q1">
        <option selected disabled>----</option>
        <option>Selected A Group</option>
        <option>Selected B Group</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here I've made the code as clean as possible: just the default select is shown at the start. The `action=""` attribute should be changed to where you submit the function.

And the JavaScript:

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/q/4793604/1256925
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var furtherSelects = {
    'Selected A Group': ['Selected C Group', 'Selected D Group'],
    'Selected B Group': ['Selected E Group', 'Selected F Group'],
    'Selected C Group': ['Selected G Group', 'Selected H Group'],
    'Selected D Group': ['Selected I Group', 'Selected J Group', 'Selected K Group'],
    'Selected E Group': ['Selected G Group', 'Selected H Group'],
    'Selected F Group': ['Selected I Group', 'Selected J Group', 'Selected K Group'],
}

function checkField(){
    addSelects = furtherSelects[this.value];
    if (!addSelects) { //For the final load of selects, add a button to submit
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = 'Submit';
        button.id='submitQuestionForm';
        insertAfter(this, button);
        return;
    }
    var sel = document.createElement('select');
    var Q_num = parseInt(this.name.substr(1))+1;
    var siblingSelects = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i=siblingSelects.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        if (parseInt(siblingSelects[i].name.substr(1)) >= Q_num) {
            siblingSelects[i].remove();
        }
    }
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitQuestionForm');
    if (submitButton) submitButton.remove();
    sel.setAttribute('name', 'Q'+Q_num);
    sel.addEventListener('change', checkField); //Make each extra element have another checkField
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = '----';
    option.disabled = true;
    option.selected = true;
    sel.appendChild(option); //Add the default option first
    for (var i=0;i<addSelects.length;i++) {
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = addSelects[i];
        sel.appendChild(option);
    }
    insertAfter(this, sel);
}
addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('questionForm')
            .getElementsByTagName('select')[0]
            .addEventListener('change', checkField);
});
```

Here I've put all the options for the selects that show after selecting another option in a single object. Here all the values for the selects are defined, with an array of options to add when that option is selected. For example if I select `Selected A Group` I'll see a select with 2 options: `Selected C Group` and `Selected D Group`.

What the event handler does is this: It first checks if there's a list of options defined for the selected option in the `furtherSelects` object (so, if `furtherSelects` has a property with the name equal to the selected value). If so, it adds a submit button, and otherwise it adds the specified select tag.

It first goes through a list of all the other select tags though, to see if the question they belong to (the 3rd select belongs to the 3rd question) is a question that lies behind the question that is being modified. If so, it removes that select element. It also removes the button by default if it is there, since this part of the function will only run if there is another select to add, which means you haven't answered the final question yet.

It then creates the select tag and adds the event handler, and goes through the array of values for the select element's options, and creates each option tag and then puts that option tag in the select tag. After that, it adds the select tag to after the one that is being changed.

At the bottom there is a simple `onload` event listener, which adds the `onchange` event listener to the first select element.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks! was really helpful. I would like to ask 1 more thing that How to for this condition-->
IF user selects option A and Option C then execute 1st condition else if user selects option C and option E then execute 2nd condition Basically here there is AND condition in html so how to do this?

Comment: @AshishM Do you mean something like that you need to select option A first, and then change your selection to option C? Or do you mean that you've got a select tag where you can select multiple options at once, and then you need to select the A and C options?

Comment: @ joeytje50 Thanks for your quick reply! Please go through this -> http://jsfiddle.net/3GkrX/ As you can see in the fiddle after selecting GROUP A then other options are continued. **I want that to continue for any number of selection**
**Also at last iteration it should display a SUBMIT button that will navigate to a specific URL depending upon options selected previously In short Submit button "should not navigate to only a SINGLE URL ALL THE TIME instead it should depend on choices that user would make""**

Comment: I'm working on a working version, but just a few quick notes: Firstly, You can only assign an attribute once, so if you assign `id="test1"` you can't afterwards assign `id="name"`. And secondly, if you add [both the `selected` and `disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) to your default selected `<option>` tag, it'll be the default option, but people won't be able to select it after picking another option.

Comment: @AshishM I've added a new section which deals with the further question you asked here. I hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: @ joeytje50 **Perfect answer! wish could give you 100+ Bounty** Thanks for your help. **Instead of my question rated a -4 still you took the initiative to reply and solve it. Really appreciable :) Keep doing the Good Work**

Comment: @ joeytje50 There is only 1 condition for submit button which means it can navigate to only 1 URL no matter whatever user selects from option tag ?

Comment: @AshishM The condition to show the submit button is that there's no defined list of options to add. This means that the form's target URL will have a Q1 to Q3 [parameter in its query](http://enwp.org/Query_string), whose values depend on the given answer. If you build in more select tags (for example you add a `Selected G Group` property to `furtherSelects`) it will create a query with URL parameters Q1 to Q4. The best thing to do when handling this is to use a loop to go through each of the URL parameters, and see what their value is. You can get the query via `document.location.search` in JS