# add element after in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add element ("br tag in my example") before and after an element in JavaScreipt:

In other words I need the equivalent of the following but in JavaScipt:

```
$('<br />').insertBefore('#id1');
$('<br />').insertAfter('#id1');
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/Wj5fd/4/)

Comment: What is wrong with Jquery in the first place??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do insert After() in JavaScript without using a library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)

Comment: Nothing wrong with my JQuery, but I need its equivalent in JavaScript!

Comment: @user3421904 here was my Google query: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+element+after

Comment: I actually bet you can solve whatever problem you're having with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be straight forward, `insertBefore` is available in native JS as well, so insert one BR tag before the element, then get the next sibling element and insert a BR before that, which would also be right after the targeted element :

```
var elem = document.getElementById('id1');
var br   = document.createElement('br');
elem.parentNode.insertBefore(br.cloneNode(false), elem);
elem.parentNode.insertBefore(br.cloneNode(false), elem.nextSibling);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Wj5fd/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer

```
var parentGuest = document.getElementById("one");
var childGuest = document.createElement("br");
parentGuest.parentNode.insertBefore(childGuest,parentGuest);
parentGuest.parentNode.insertBefore(childGuest,parentGuest.nextSibling);
```

([JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/prakashcbe/j667q/18/))

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="a"><div id="a1">Coffee</div><div id="a2">Tea</div></div><br/><br/>
<div id="b"><div id="b1">Mother</div><div id="b2">Father</div></div>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
//insertBefore
var newItem1=document.createElement("hr");
var parent1=document.getElementById("a");
var child1=document.getElementById("a2");

parent1.insertBefore(newItem1,child1);

//insertAfter There is no insert Atfter Method in Java Script




}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```