# Append div before/after texbox places it within

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NewComent" TextMode="MultiLine" onkeyup="textEdit(this);" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**JS**

```
function textEdit(Inputelement) {
    var count = Inputelement.value.length;
    var newElement = document.getElementById(Inputelement.id + "_123");
    console.log(newElement);
    if (newElement == null) {
        newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.setAttribute('id', Inputelement.id + "_123");
        newElement.innerHTML = (350 - count) + " letters left";
        Inputelement.insertBefore(newElement, Inputelement.parent);
        //Inputelement.appendChild(newElement);
        console.log("Inner");
    }
    else {
        newElement.innerHTML = (350 - count) + " letters left";
        console.log("Outer");
    }
}
```

The code is supposed to take a textbok and add a counter below it.
but here is the catch. It places the div inside of it making it non visual.

**Output (inspector)**

```
<textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$QandA$ViewQA$QAListView$ctrl0$ViewQAComment$NewComent" rows="2" cols="20" id="MainContent_QandA_ViewQA_QAListView_ViewQAComment_0_NewComent_0" onkeyup="textEdit(this);">
    <div id="MainContent_QandA_ViewQA_QAListView_ViewQAComment_0_NewComent_0_123">344 letters left</div>
</textarea>
```

Using insertBefore and appendChild both result in the same problem, at least on Opera which basically is Chrome. So here i am, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question has been already answered [(link to answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library).

With the way that you are using `appendChild()` you are appending `newElement` as a child element inside of `Inputelement`. Apart from the existing answer, replacing the `insertBefore()` line with the following code should also work:

```
Inputelement.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, Inputelement.nextSibling);
```

Comment: That worked. nice little hack calling the parent and then digging down.

Answer (score 2):

That should fix it:

```
textEdit = function(Inputelement) {
    var count = Inputelement.value.length;
    var newElement = document.getElementById(Inputelement.id + "_123");
    if (newElement == null) {
        newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.setAttribute('id', Inputelement.id + "_123");
        newElement.innerHTML = (350 - count) + " letters left";

        Inputelement.parentNode.appendChild(newElement, Inputelement)
   }
   else {
        newElement.innerHTML = (350 - count) + " letters left";
   }
}
```

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tc7qsaaL/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's insertBefore does insert the element before, however plain old javascript has an insertBefore method as well which inserts it inside the element.

Javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp

jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Comment: Fancy js speciffic thing then :) ty for the explanation.