# getElementsByClassName and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

Can someone explain how to appendChild to a parent `<div class="...">`
and solve this ?

The innerHTML should set the variable **str** after **every** `<div class='categories'> </div>`
it created dynamically when you set a value to the texts and press the button "press"

```js
function addField() {
    var categoryValue = document.getElementById("newCateg").value;
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById("newField").value;
// var selOption = document.option[selectedIndex.text];

    var newCategoryNode = document.getElementsByClassName('categories');

    var categoryPart1 = [
        '    <div class="categories">',
        '<input type="checkbox" class="check"/>  <a class="titles">'].join('');

    var categoryPart2 = [
        '</a>',
        '    <hr/>',
        '   <input type="checkbox" class="check"/> ' ].join('');

    var categoryPart3 = [
        '        <input type="text"  />',
        '   <br> </br>',
        '<hr/>',
        '</div>'].join('');

    var str=categoryPart1 + categoryValue + categoryPart2 + "" +       fieldValue + "" + categoryPart3;
    
   
    for (var i = 0; i < newCategoryNode.length; i++) {
        newCategoryNode[i].innerHTML=str;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="newCateg" />
        <input type="text" id="newField" />
        <div class="categories">
            <p class="titles">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" onchange="checkAll('divID',true,elem)" />FUN</p>
            <hr/>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />D
                <input type="text" />
                </br>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
            <label>S</label>
            <input type="text" id="c1" />
            </br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
            <label>A</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="addField()" value="Press">
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: *appendChild* is for appending DOM elements, not strings. Perhaps you want `node[i].innerHTML = str;` or perhaps `node[i].innerHTML += str;`.

Comment: alright,then how i append the innerHTML to the parrent class?

Comment: Oh, and get rid of the *faux* XML markup style, it's an HTML document. ;-)

Comment: What do you by "*append*"? Concatenate?

Comment: let me explain ..i will edit the code according to RobG

Comment: Typo: `document.getElemensByClassName` => `document.getElementsByClassName`. Another typo in your question title. Also, where are you using `newCategory`?

Comment: @PM append i mean set the str after the <div class="categories"></div>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library

Comment: @RobG: `.insertAdjacentHTML()` Please don't tell people to do `.innerHTML += str;`

Comment: everyone says everything here.only god knows who is right or wrong here...
i am confused

Comment: @squint—that produces a different result to what I was suggesting, but I think it's the outcome the OP wants (i.e. to insert siblings to the div, not content).

Comment: All here see try to look Mr.Genius and cannot understand 20 simple lines of code about what i want to do...
 
Create dynamically cascading divs which  every div takes the values from the two texts...no overwritting but add a div after another div etc.

Comment: everyone is trying to help you here actually.It appears that  you are not sure what you are trying to do with your code.

Comment: @RobG: Not sure what you mean. `.insertAdjacentHTML()` is capable of inserting at one of four different positions relative to the element on which it's invoked, one of which would be at the end of its content, like `.appendChild()` does. However it's non-destructive, unlike `.innerHTML += ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="newCateg" />
        <input type="text" id="newField" />
        <div class="categories">
            <p class="titles">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" onchange="checkAll('divID',true,elem)" />FUN</p>
            <hr/>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />D
                <input type="text" />
                </br>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
            <label>S</label>
            <input type="text" id="c1" />
            </br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
            <label>A</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="addField()" value="Press">
    </body>

    <script>
        function addField() {
                var categoryValue = document.getElementById("newCateg").value;
                var fieldValue = document.getElementById("newField").value;
            // var selOption = document.option[selectedIndex.text];

                var newCategory = document.getElementsByClassName('categories');

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.setAttribute('class', 'categories');

                var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.setAttribute('class', 'titles');

                var hr = document.createElement('hr');

                var input_check = document.createElement('input');
                    input_check.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
                    input_check.setAttribute('class', 'check');

                var input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');

                var br = document.createElement('br');

                var textnode = document.createTextNode(fieldValue);

                div.appendChild(input);
                div.appendChild(a);
                div.appendChild(hr);
                div.appendChild(input_check);
                div.appendChild(textnode);
                div.appendChild(input);
                div.appendChild(br);
                div.appendChild(br);
                console.log(div);

                var node = document.getElementsByClassName('categories');

                for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
                    node[i].appendChild(div);
                }
            }

    </script>

</html>
```

hope this could give you idea on how to do it.

you cannot use appendChild to a node using a string it shoud also be a DOM element

you can check on document.createElement and document.createTextNode function

hope it would help you more on your understanding

Comment: Finally someone understood what my code wants to do...
Thanks!

With my own way is this possible to do this?What you think.

Comment: to avoid createElement and use stings passing them to innerHTML as i try to do

Answer (score 0):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild), `Node.appendChild()` wants a `Node` object as its argument. It won't create one from a string of markup, so you'll have to create it yourself.

You can use `document.createElement()` to create a `Node` object, then you can set its `innerHTML` as you like. Once the `Node` is all set how you want, you can add it to the DOM using `appendChild()`.

Comment: this is false i can guess .So how i will append a string to a previous div
   ....             
 var newNode=createElement("div");
               newNode=str;
                for (var i = 0; i < newCategoryNode.length; i++) {
                    newCategoryNode[i].appendChild(newNode);

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You create a div, then immediately replace it with a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use appendChild() mehtod it doesn't work this way.First you have to create a child  using element.createElement() method.Now concentrating on your code i encountered some problem. your `getElementsByClassName` is returning a nodelist containing all the elements having same class.So if you want to grab it provide it an index.As you have only one it's better to provide [0] index to it.

```
var newCategoryNode = document.getElementsByClassName('categories')[0];
```

if you don't provide index in getElementsByClassName()  you can also access it

```
 newCategoryNode[0].innerHTMM=str
```

i removed `for loop` from you code.If you want to use loop use `for...in` loop instead as it is a list of object.

```
var newCategoryNode = document.getElementsByClassName('categories');
               for(key in newCategoryNode){
                   newCategoryNode[key].innerHTML=str;
               }
```

you haven't defined `checkAll()` function related to one of your input tag.That surely get you an error.I've modified your code and it might give you the result you want

```js
            function addField() {
   console.log('logged');
                var categoryValue = document.getElementById("newCateg").value;
                var fieldValue = document.getElementById("newField").value;
            // var selOption = document.option[selectedIndex.text];

                var newCategoryNode = document.getElementsByClassName('categories')[0];

                var categoryPart1 = [
                    '    <div class="categories">',
                    '<input type="checkbox" class="check"/>  <a class="titles">'].join('');
  console.log(categoryPart1);
                var categoryPart2 = [
                    '</a>',
                    '    <hr/>',
                    '   <input type="checkbox" class="check"/> ' ].join('');

                var categoryPart3 = [
                    '        <input type="text"  />',
                    '   <br> </br>',
                    '<hr/>',
                    '</div>'].join('');

                var str=categoryPart1 + categoryValue + categoryPart2 +   fieldValue + "" + categoryPart3;
                
                console.log(str);
              
      newCategoryNode.innerHTML =str;
   
     }
```

```html
        <input type="text" id="newCateg" />
        <input type="text" id="newField" />
        <div class="categories">
            <p class="titles">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />FUN</p>
            <hr/>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />D
                <input type="text" />
                </br>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
            <label>S</label>
            <input type="text" id="c1" />
            </br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
            <label>A</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <input type="button" onClick="addField();" value="Press">
```

Comment: *"[...] getElementsByClassName is returning an array"*. No it's not, it's returning a `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`. They can be accessed and iterated over like arrays but they don't have any of the arrays methods.

Comment: *"i removed for loop from you code.If you want to use loop use for...in loop instead as it is a list of object"* Sorry, but that's completely wrong. He should *not* use `for-in` on this type of collection because it may include other items besides just the elements. The `for` loop is correct.

Comment: he can check for 'length' element with an if statement,if you are calling it an issue

Comment: Could be `.length`, could be something else. Either way, his loop was the way to do it; `for-in` is not. Also `for-in` doesn't guarantee numeric order and is slower. There's just no reason to use it on arrays or array-like objects.