# Javascript / Save input data into a table cell

Tags: javascript, html

The structure is:

1. You click on a cell,
2. The pop-up window appears,
3. You type something on the input fields.

What I want is to store the typed data into the cell which was clicked.

This could be perfectly done with `Angular.js`, but I need to do it using Javascript only (no frameworks, libraries etc.).

Here's my table with the pop-up window where the input fields are.

[image]

I have been trying to store the data simply by using `.innerHTML` method, but it just deletes the dates and inserts my text.

```
  var cell = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i=0; i<cell.length; i++) {
     cell[i].onclick = function() {
        var data = this.getAttribute('data-cell');
        editEvent = document.getElementById('addevent');//The pop-up window
        editEvent.style.cssText ='display: block;';
        this.style.position = 'relative';

        this.innerHTML = " "//??? I want the inputs data to be inserted here
```

I also have those input data stored in localStorage. Perhaps, there's an easier way to transfer the data from localStorage into the cell? Because it is exactly what I need there.

Please, help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why in the world would you tag a question with "angular" if it is explicitly **not** intended to be done with angular? removing the tag

Comment: I don't get it, what's the actual question here?

Comment: `.innerHTML` is not the attribute you're looking for. `.value` is what you need instead.

Comment: Have you tried **setAttribute** **getAttribute**? Do you want to store it into cell dom element, or to show it in html??

Comment: @Paul S. The actual question is how to store the data from input fields into the cell in the calendar.

Comment: can you show the code for the Table (HTML)?

Comment: @ViROscar The table is created with JS, like that 
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

Comment: @skobaljic It seems like setAttribute getAttribute change nothing((
I think I need it to be stored into cell DOM element (in order to the user could edit it later just by clicking).

Comment: i will recommend you to mention that because "innerhtml" will replace everything and i guess nobody here know how do you add the date to the cell.

Comment: Use html5 [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset), transfer all from localStorage. (but since you have everything in localStorage, why do you need it into dom at all?)

Comment: @skobaljic I need it to be displayed in the cell. It is supposed to be a sort of task in the calender. I stored the data in localStorage like, let's say:
Event: Birthday
Participants: Kurt, Dave, Kris...
etc....
So, it is supposed to be shown in the calendar and be available for a user to edit it whenever he wants.

Comment: But you do not want to show us html code for one cell. It should be something like `<td class="has_event or_other_class"><span class="day">12.</span><span class="text"></span></td>`... Tell us how it should look like without and with data inside.

Comment: @skobaljic It's the same as I wrote above. The cells also generated by JS:
document.createElement('td');
Whole table generated via JS. 
The names of the Days were created by document.createTextNode(), etc. There's no actual "manual" mark-up, if we can say so.

Comment: you can use the chrome console in order to see the code generated by js. if you can show that information, it will be helpful.

Comment: @skobaljic Ah, sorry, I didn't understand at once.
Here it is
<div id = "cal">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td data-cell = "27-1-2015">
        "27, "
        "Tuesday"
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) to read/write custom data attributes. An [example app is HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5d4vh891/). You can also work with localStorage directly, than the unique ID would be date.

In order to show text/data into calendar cell, you need a placeholder. In my example each table cell is in this format:

```
<td>
    <div data-date="6-1-2015" class="box">
        <span class="day">6</span>
        <span class="text"></span> <!-- this is a placeholder -->
    </div>
</td>
```

This way it is easy to find clickable cells:

```
// Select clickable cells
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
```

than to bind click events (to open modal window):

```
// Bind clickable cells
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var thisCell = this;
        var thisDate = thisCell.dataset.date;
        var thisEvent = thisCell.dataset.event;
        var thisParticipants = thisCell.dataset.participants;
        var thisDescription = thisCell.dataset.description;
        date.innerHTML = thisDate;
        event.value = thisEvent || '';
        participants.value = thisParticipants || '';
        description.value = thisDescription || '';
        modal.style.display = 'block';
    });
};
```

Saving data is piece of cake:

```
// Bind save button
submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var thisDate = date.innerHTML;
    var thisEvent = event.value;
    var thisParticipants = participants.value;
    var thisDescription = description.value;
    var thisCell = document.querySelector('[data-date="' + thisDate + '"]');
    // Assign data to table cell
    thisCell.dataset.event = thisEvent;
    thisCell.dataset.participants = thisParticipants;
    thisCell.dataset.description = thisDescription;
    // Show on screen
    var textField = thisCell.querySelector('.text'); //-- This is our container
    textField.innerHTML = '\
        <span class="eve">' + thisEvent + '</span>\
        <span class="par">' + thisParticipants + '</span>\
        <span class="des">' + thisDescription + '</span>\
    ';
    modal.style.display = 'none';
});
```

and after filling data, table cell looks like this:

```
<td>
    <div data-date="6-1-2015" class="box" data-event="Event Title" data-participants="John, Robert" data-description="Football">
        <span class="day">6</span>
        <span class="text">
            <span class="eve">Event Title</span>
            <span class="par">John, Robert</span>
            <span class="des">Football</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

For more info, please take a look at Fiddle, code is huge to paste it here.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't (yet) posted the generated HTML, so I'm guessing you have only one HTML element per day. That's why when you use `element.innerHTML`, you change their whole content.

Create empty elements (`div` or `span` would do) *next* to the date elements.

Like so:

```
var date, dateBefore;
for(...) {
    // your existing date element
    dateBefore = date;
    date = document.createElement("div");
    // some code to insert the day into it, like date.innerHTML = "26";

    // a placeholder for your input
    datePlaceholder = document.createElement("div");

    // add the placeholder element to the DOM
    document.body.insertBefore(datePlaceholder, dateBefore);

    // insert your empty placeholder right before it, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library
    document.body.insertBefore(date, datePlaceholder);
}
```

You may want to to put both the `date` and `datePlaceholder` in the same div.

**Edit:** using this example, you would have to change your selector (td -> div) and make sure the placeholders are big enough so they "catch" the clicks. For instance, add a `.placeholder` class and make sure to give them a size in CSS:

```
.placeholder {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* debug border to make sure it takes the whole cell */
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```