# HTML & Javascript create new image on page for each image in a directory

Tags: javascript, html, image, loops

I'm trying to create an images on the page to represent thumbnails, however my current code only shows the last image on in the directory. How do I make the for loop create a new image on my page each time it iterates.

```
<img id="tpic" src="http://example.net/test%20page/001.jpg" width="20%" height="20%">

<script type="text/javascript">
var y = 1;
var picurl2 = "http://example.net/test%20page/00"+y+".jpg";
document.getElementById("tpic").src=picurl2;
document.getElementById("divThumb").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pic2").src;

for (y = 1; y < 18; y++)
{
  if (y<10){
    picurl2 = "http://example.net/test%20page/00"+y+".jpg";
  }
else{
   picurl2 = "http://example.net/test%20page%20/0"+y+".jpg";
 }

  document.getElementById("tpic").src=picurl2;

}

</script>
```

Comment: ignore the  document.getElementById("divThumb").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pic2").src.

Comment: It appears that you are updating the image source to the same ID, so naturally, the sources ARE changing, but it happens so quickly that it appears to only show the last image in the iteration because thats where it stops.

Do you want to general all image thumbnails at once, or do you want to  CYCLE through the image thumbnails in that same Div with there being some kind of pause or transition as its shown?

Comment: Try adding new `<img>`'s with the help of these functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array to hold all of your images.

```
var imgs = ["one.jpg", "two.jpg", "three.jpg"];
```

Loop through the array and add a new image to the page for each image in the array

```
for(i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML += "<img src='"+ imgs[i] + "' class='images'></img>";
}
```

Full code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fcetjyqk/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use **[document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)** in your for loop to create the images and append their `src` attributes  like this:

```
for (y = 1; y < 18; y++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    if (y < 10) {
        img.src = "http://example.net/test%20page/00" + y + ".jpg";
    } else {
        img.src = "http://example.net/test%20page%20/0" + y + ".jpg";
    }

    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Here's a [**DEMO fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4k6deu9d/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```html
<div id="placehere"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isIE() {
    var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
  }

  function createImg(src, width, height) {
    var img = isIE() ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;
    if (width != null) img.style.width = width;
    if (height != null) img.style.height = height;
    return img;
  }

  for (y = 1; y < 18; y++) {
    var picurl2;
    if (y < 10) {
      picurl2 = "http://example.net/test%20page/00" + y + ".jpg";
    } else {
      picurl2 = "http://example.net/test%20page%20/0" + y + ".jpg";
    }
    document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(createImg(picurl2, "20%", "20%"));
  }
</script>
```