# Javascript function not working for multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an element after multiple selected elements. The problem is that it only seems to apply it to a single element. [The code is in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sansSpoon/h4a83s8o/).

```
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2"></p>

<script>
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var errorNode = document.createElement("span");
errorNode.className = "error";
errorNode.innerHTML = 'You must specify a value';
var errorField = document.getElementById('1');
errorField.innerHTML = 'para 1';
insertAfter(errorField, errorNode);
errorField = document.getElementById('2');
errorField.innerHTML = 'para 2';
insertAfter(errorField, errorNode);

</script>
```

In this case it only adds it to the 2nd para. If you comment out the 2nd function call it correctly adds it to the first para. It is however successfully updating the para contents.

Any help appreciated in advanced.

Comment: Out of curiosity why have you created an alternate version of `Node.insertBefore()`?

Comment: It's to place the element after the one you want. I got it from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just creating 1 `errorNode` element, and moving it around in the dom when you are calling the `insertBefore()` each time.

Instead you need to create a new instance of the node, if you want to add it in different locations. You can create a clone of the node to do that like

```js
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var errorNode = document.createElement("span");
errorNode.className = "ms-formvalidation";
errorNode.innerHTML = '<span role="alert">You must specify a value for this required field.<br></span>';
var errorField = document.getElementById('1');
errorField.innerHTML = 'para 1';
insertAfter(errorField, errorNode.cloneNode(true));
errorField = document.getElementById('2');
errorField.innerHTML = 'para 2';
insertAfter(errorField, errorNode.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2"></p>
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Good to know about the element cloning, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Node.insertBefore` the second time, it moves your `errorNode` from the first to the second paragraph. As stated on [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-952280727):

> If the `newChild` is already in the tree, it is first removed.

If you want two error nodes, you need to create two, populate each with your text, and add each to its own paragraph.