# How to add a td just next to a td using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a piece of code to implement an "Add New Deadlines" functionality.

I have 5 "Add" buttons:

```
 <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;"
 onclick="addDeadline(1)" id="button_1">Add Deadline</td>

 <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;"
 onclick="addDeadline(2)" id="button_2">Add Deadline</td>

 <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;"
 onclick="addDeadline(3)" id="button_3">Add Deadline</td>

 <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;"
 onclick="addDeadline(4)" id="button_4">Add Deadline</td>

 <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;"
 onclick="addDeadline(5)" id="button_5">Add Deadline</td>
```

I want to implement a javascript `addDeadline(num)` that can insert the below td after the clicked button.

```
<td>Deadline 1</td>
<td>Deadline 2</td>
<td>Deadline 3</td>
<td>Deadline 4</td>
<td>Deadline 5</td>
```

**"Deadline 1"** should be inserted after the `button_1` if it is clicked.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of 5 button you can use one button and bind a function which will create TD and append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your code to this to make it work (no jquery just pure js):

```js
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode,   referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function addDeadline(num, caller) {
  var el = document.createElement("td");
  el.innerHTML = "Deadline" + num;
  insertAfter(caller, el);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="javascript:addDeadline(1,this)" id="button_1">Add Deadline</td>

    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="addDeadline(2,this)" id="button_2">Add Deadline</td>

    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="addDeadline(3,this)" id="button_3">Add Deadline</td>

    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="addDeadline(4,this)" id="button_4">Add Deadline</td>

    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="addDeadline(5,this)" id="button_5">Add Deadline</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

To insert new element after clicked element. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)

`removeAttribute` will remove `click` handler. If you do not want to stop adding `td`s then remove this line..

> [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will return clicked element

```js
function addDeadline(num) {
  var newElem = document.createElement('td');
  newElem.innerText = 'Deadline ' + num;
  event.target.parentNode.insertBefore(newElem, event.target.nextSibling);
  event.target.removeAttribute('onclick')
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="addDeadline(1)" id="button_1">Add Deadline</td>

    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="addDeadline(2)" id="button_2">Add Deadline</td>

    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="addDeadline(3)" id="button_3">Add Deadline</td>

    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="addDeadline(4)" id="button_4">Add Deadline</td>

    <td class="imgButton" style="width: 185px; text-align: center;" onclick="addDeadline(5)" id="button_5">Add Deadline</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/9dajeqgq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

You can use that as an example, of course modifying it according to your table. You can point to the table with the `id`, and the add the elements you want.

Or:

```
document.getElementById('TABLE_ID').innerHTML += '<td> Deadline X </td>';
```

X can be stored in a variable.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can write `insertAfter()` function like this:

```
function addDeadline(num) {
  $( "<td>Deadline "+num+"</td>" ).insertAfter( "#button_"+num ); 
}
```