# Javascript DOMParser.parseFromString giving parse error

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

When doing this in console, why do I get a parse error?

```
TR = '<TR id=line1 class="myClass"><INPUT id=input1 type=hidden> <INPUT id=input2> <TD style="PADDING-LEFT: 20px" align=left> <IMG class=im border=0 src="images/img.gif"> Hello </TD><!-- comment --> <TD id=cell1 align=right></TD> <TD id=cell2 align=right></TD> <TD align=middle>&nbsp; </TD> <TD align=middle></TD></TR>';
parser = new DOMParser()
xmlDocument = _parser.parseFromString(TR, "text/xml");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem (I assume it's not the one you're experiencing, rather that this code is erroneously copy-pasted): Your variable name is `parser`, not `_parser`.

Your main problem is that you're trying to parse HTML as XML, which will work ***IF*** your HTML is also valid XML. But yours isn't. Quote your attributes for a start. That's what

```
error on line 1 at column 8: AttValue: " or ' expected
```

means.

After you do that, close your void elements. It's OK to leave off the trailing slash in HTML5, but not within the stricter rules of XML.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new `DOMParser()` and assign it to a variable named `parser`:

```
parser = new DOMParser()
```

But then you reference an undeclared variable `_parser` on the next line:

```
xmlDocument = _parser.parseFromString(TR, "text/xml");
```

If you replace `_parser` with `parser`, the console error should go away.