# Why does my HTML div not appear on my HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to be able to append a replay button on to my canvas when the player loses my javascript game.

I have HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" >

</canvas>
```

And part of my javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

...

if (gameover){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<button onclick="window.reload">replay</button>';
    canvas.appendChild(div);
}
```

When I inspect my window the HTML has been added, but it doesn't show up on the screen?

Comment: Canvas is a void element. You can give backup text inside of that but not an element.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy so how would I allow a player to reload the window?

Comment: You have to place the button outside the canvas. And you need to position it to display over the canvas.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you can also give backup elements, but they won't be parsed if the canvas element is supported.

Answer (score 2):

The canvas element cannot render HTML, You have to add a new sibling to the canvas, so your HTML code renders after the canvas.

Maybe this would help you:
[How to do insert After() in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)