# Adding div tag below another div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` tag with class `divstudent`, lets say this is `div1` tag. Now I want to create another div tag `div2` dynamically below this `div1` tag, not inside of the `div1` tag. I want to create outside of `div1` tag using javascript. How can I do that?

```html
"div1"
<div class="divstudent"></div>

<!-- i want to be like this -->
<!-- "div1" -->
<div></div>

<!-- "div2" -->
<div></div>

<!-- "div3" -->
<div></div>
```

Comment: Just a side note, HTML comments are denoted `<!-- Like this -->`

Comment: Pretty much the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library

Comment: What have you tried? BTW: It is quite a bit easier to reference a specific element if you give it a unique `id`, in addition to a `class`.

Comment: Are you really wanting to remove the `class="divstudent"`?

Comment: yes i want to remove the class,and i need to create new div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Divs creator</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var divReference = document.querySelector('.divstudent');
            var divCounter = 0;
            divReference.addEventListener('click', function () {
                var divToCreate = document.createElement('div');
                divToCreate.innerHTML = ++divCounter;
                divReference.parentNode.appendChild(divToCreate);
            }, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divstudent">
        <input type="button" value="add div below divstudent">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  $("div").eq(0).after("<div>This is div 2</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  This is div 1
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), just use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("div").eq(0).after("<div>This is div 2</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  This is div 1
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One significant difference in methods is if you choose to create the elements first using [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and then insert the elements, or create and insert the elements in one step using one of the methods that allows you to insert HTML text.

Because it is simpler, but not necessarily better, the examples below show creating and inserting the two `<div>` elements in a single step using methods that allow inserting HTML text into the DOM.

**JavaScript:**
One is to use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and specify that it is to be inserted `afterend` of the element you are using.

[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) is used to find the first `<div class="divstudent">`. Then `insertAdjacentHTML()` is used to add the additional `<div>` elements.  [`Element.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is then used to remove the `class="divstudent"`. Note: if we had just wanted to set teh `class` to something different, even `''`, then we could have used [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className).

**NOTE:** In this answer, text identifying each `<div>` has been added to the `<div>`s so there is something visible in the examples in this answer.

```js
//Find the first <div class="divstudent"> in the document
var studentDiv = document.querySelector('div.divstudent');
//Insert two new <div> elements.
studentDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div>2</div><div>3</div>');
//Remove the class="divstudent"
studentDiv.removeAttribute('class');
```

```html
<div class="divstudent">1</div>
```

**jQuery:**
While your question is tagged jQuery, a comment you posted implies you are just using JavaScript. Thus, I am not sure if jQuery works for you.

If you want to use jQuery, then you can use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to add the `<div>` elements.  You can then use [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to remove the `class="divstudent"`.

```js
// Get the first <div class="divstudent">.
//   Store it in a variable so we only walk the DOM once.
var $studentDiv = $('div.divstudent').eq(0); 
//Add the two new <div> elements 
$studentDiv.after('<div>2</div><div>3</div>');
//Remove the class="divstudent"
$studentDiv.removeAttr('class');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divstudent">1</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You create a new div (in js), then just append your newDiv, after the target div. Something along the lines of in vanilla js:

```
// Create your new div
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");   
newDiv.innerText = "New Div!"; 
// Grab the div you want to insert your new div after   
var target_div = document.querySelector("div.divstudent");
// Insert newDiv after target_div (before the thing after it)
target_div.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, target_div.nextSibling);
```

Comment: Whoops, your right, was coding straight in to the box :p have fixed it

Comment: its not working for me,i am using javacript,i think i shd write function for insertAfter

Comment: Have updated it with fix. As Makyen pointed out I'd imagined the insertAfter method since i was writing straight in to the answer box.