# how do i add HTML below an element with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<h1 id="site-title" class="page-title"> Website Name </h1>
```

And I want to add the following direclty underneath it, but I can't do it in the HTML so I would need to with javascript/jquery.

```
<p id="site-tagline" class="site-subtitle">Tagline, Tagline, Tagline</p>
```

How would I best do this?

I have this but nothing is showing up on the rendered page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> $("<h1>Fashion</h1>").insertAfter("#site-title"); </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do insert After() in JavaScript without using a library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)

Comment: Use native function `insertAfter`.

Comment: @Mahi thanks but pretty new to this. that link seems very complicated.

Comment: use append method of jquery

Comment: @Mahi tried this but not working 
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> $("<h1>Fashion</h1>").insertAfter("#site-title"); </script>`

Comment: @charlietfl updated problem statement. and there is site-title. see the first code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working, please check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvfqb55h/).

```
   $("<h1>Fashion</h1>").insertAfter("#site-title");
```

It's not working for you? You need to check jQuery errors.

Comment: ah thanks. ok so the error is `(index):58 Uncaught TypeError: "#site-title.page-title".append is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ (index):58`

Comment: Sorry, I think you make a mistake, you get an error with ""#site-title.page-title", but we don't have this element in my code above...

Answer (score 0):

[After](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
$("h1").after('<p id="site-tagline" class="site-subtitle">Tagline, Tagline, Tagline</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="site-title" class="page-title"> Website Name </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the taglines using append command

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#site-tagline" ).append( '<h1 id="site-title" class="page-title"> Tagline 1 </h1>' );

$( "#site-tagline" ).append( ',' );
$( "#site-tagline" ).append( '<h1 id="site-title" class="page-title"> Tagline 2 </h1>' );

$( "#site-tagline" ).append( ',' );
$( "#site-tagline" ).append( '<h1 id="site-title" class="page-title"> Tagline 3 </h1>' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="site-tagline" class="site-subtitle"></p>
```