# insertBefore to insert after?

Tags: javascript

I have this working code but instead of it inserting before I would like to insert after. I'm just not sure how to go about this. Thanks in advance

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownBody, false);

function keyDownBody(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
if(keyCode==65) {
  myFunction();
}
}
function myFunction()
{var a = document.createElement("IMG");

a.src="img/one/a1.gif?rand_number=" + Math.random();

document.body.insertBefore(a,document.body.firstElementChild);}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownBody2, false);

function keyDownBody2(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
if(keyCode==66) {
  myFunctionb();
}
}
function myFunctionb()
{var b = document.createElement("IMG");

b.src="img/one/b1.gif?rand_number=" + Math.random();

document.body.insertBefore(b,document.body.firstElementChild);}
```

Comment: There is no `insertAfter`. You have to find the next element and insert before it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do insert After() in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) function.
I have changed your code to do it in one place.

https://jsfiddle.net/w05Lem0s/

Simply do:

```
document.body.appendChild(a,document.body.firstElementChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find next element and insert before it

```
function myFunctionb() {
  var b = document.createElement("IMG");

  b.src = "img/one/b1.gif?rand_number=" + Math.random();

  document.body.insertBefore(b, document.body.firstElementChild.nextSibling);
}
```