# How to add i tag after input tag

Tags: javascript, html

My source code is:

```
<div id="id1" class=class1>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="something">uh, this is label</label>
</div>
```

I would like add i tag after input tag.
Source code will be looks like:

```
<div id="id1" class=class1>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="something"> <i class="genius"></i> uh, this is label</label>
</div>
```

Is it possible by JavaScript?

Comment: What research have you done, and what have you attempted on your own prior to asking us? Or are you just asking "Is it possible?" - in which case, "Yes. Have a nice day."

Comment: @RajeshPaudel Why use expensive APIs like jQuery when you don't have to? And @Shruti, `<i>` tags are often used for icons, etc, that make use of CSS pseudo-elements. [**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/99ngwwcv/)

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793630/3561995

Comment: Hi great question, i did not tried yet but i am just thinking how is possible, its making hard for me.

My source code is encrypted, that's why i need add this tag by using JavaScript.

If you have any idea, please share me.

Thanks.

Comment: I have found something and as i can see its working on fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sanjida96xq2/8sQqB/16/

But unfortunately, my cms with not working due to the input fields comes through ajax loading.

Is there any solution, hows work while ajax loading?

Comment: Any idea about the ajax issue?