# Inserting code stored in variable after selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following line of code:

```
var code = document.querySelectorAll('article.shop-the-look')[0];
```

This code stores some markup that I want to insert after a given selector.
What I am looking for is more or less the equivalent to the jQuery insertAfter function, but I need it to be Vanilla JS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore). Take a look at accepted answer to: [How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

```js
var code = document.querySelectorAll('article.shop-the-look')[0];
var after = document.querySelectorAll('article.after')[0];
after.parentNode.insertBefore(code, after.nextSibling);
```

```html
<div>
<article class="shop-the-look">Shop the look</article>
<article class="after">After article, should be "Shop the look"</article>
</div>
```