# Displaying button after a div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a button with a link after a div that has no id, using Google Tag Manager. I'm taking the specific div (without id) using the code below, but when I try to put the button after that div using innerHTML, the div is replaced by the button, and if I use appendChild (commented in my code) nothing happens.

```
<script>
  var HTML = '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="button" >Send</a>'
  var title = document.getElementsByClassName("class_title");
  title[0].nextSibling.nextSibling.setAttribute("id", "newdiv");
  document.getElementById("newdiv").innerHTML = HTML;
  //getElementById("newscript").appendChild(HTML);
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793630/3966682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, to insert a node after another, you use this (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793630/3966682)):

```
referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
```

To use `insertBefore`, you should create a link element using JavaScript, and then insert it, like so:

```
<script>
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode("Send");
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.target = "_blank";
  a.href = "#";
  a.class = "button";
  var referenceNode = document.getElementsByClassName("class_title")[0].nextSibling.nextSibling;
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(a, referenceNode.nextSibling);
</script>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! With your help, I've been able to do it exactly how I wanted and now it works like a charm. I have to say that this is the only way it works for me. Thanks a lot, @d4nyll!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

Your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

In your case, do this:

```
// Create a variable for the element you want. Make it easy to read.
var element = document.getElementById("new_div");

element.parentNode.insertBefore(HTML, element.nextSibling);
```

Read the linked question to see the explanation in details.

Comment: Thanks, @beto-silva! However, I also needed some formatting for the HTML element.