# How can I show the same result jQuery (insert a <span> tag after input element ) by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am new learner to JavaScript.
I have lot of try for inser a span tag after input element.
I can do it by jQuery ,But i want to convert it JavaScript. 
please tell me anyone for my problem. 
This is my jQuery code i want to same result by JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#selector_id').after('<span class="arrow"></span>');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question in future, make sure to show some evidence (usually code) that you've attempted to answer your question before asking it here, as that'll usually help the answerer.

Your code could be translated by replacing the `jQuery(selector)` syntax with `getElementById()`, and `insertAdjacentHtml()` instead of after:

```
document.getElementById('selector_id')
  .insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="arrow"></span>');
```

There's not really a suitable replacement for `$(document).ready()`, just make sure to have your script tags at the end of your HTML before the closing `</body>` tag.

Take a look at http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ - it's a great resource for translating from jQuery to vanilla JS.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry to say still now it's not working.

Comment: I can't say any more without seeing more of your code

Comment: This is my code: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<label for="rememberme">
 <input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" value="forever" type="checkbox">
  Remember Me
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('#rememberme').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="arrow"></span>'); 
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Remove the `#` from your ID in the code `(#rememberme)` - `getElementById` is already only looking for an ID so it's not needed