# How can I make my div appear with createElement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make another div right under the existing div in the HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>    
            Media Player
        </title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
            makeOscarPlayer(document.getElementById("my-video"))
    </script>
    <body>
        <div class="my-player">
            Hello! 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

function makeOscarPlayer(){
   var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = `
    hello
`
}
```

can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I am a self-taught developer sorry if my code is not perfectly organized still learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `makeOscarPlayer()` function before you are creating it.

You need to wrap the `makeOscarPlayer()` function declaration in a script tag.

You are passing in `document.getElementById("my-video")` as a parameter to `makeOscarPlayer()`, but there is no HTML element with an id of 'my-video'. You are giving the function a parameter of `null`, while the function declaration has no parameters.

You need to tell the script where to put the new element. To do that, you grab an existing element and use `parentNode` and `insertBefore`

Here is a barebones version that I got working for your reference:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>    
          Media Player
      </title>
  </head>
  <script>
  </script>
  <body>
      <div id="my-player">
          Hello! 
      </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function makeOscarPlayer(){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = `hello`;

    // This grabs the element that you want to create a new element by
    var existingDiv = document.getElementById("my-player");

    // This tells the script where to put the new element
    existingDiv.parentNode.insertBefore( div, existingDiv.nextSibling);
  }

  // Must be called in the same script block or after the script holding the function declaration is loaded
  makeOscarPlayer();
</script>
```

For more information on how `parentNode` and `insertBefore` work, see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793630/6884283)

Answer (score 1):

You need to append that new element to a specific parent, in your case to `my-video`.

The function **[`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)** appends the new element to a parent element.

```js
function makeOscarPlayer(parent) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = 'Hello from Ele';

  parent.appendChild(div);
}

makeOscarPlayer(document.getElementById("my-video"))
```

```css
#my-player {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

#my-video div {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-player">
  Hello!
  <div id="my-video">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so I ran your code snippet, then I am trying it on my side of the code editor and it is not working. :( I feel like I am doing something wrong. I copied your code to a new file and the HTML content shows but the javascript div is still not showing

Comment: I read through the console and this was the error I received, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: @OscarP. can you post the current HTML/Code/JS?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good start, but you're calling the function incorrectly and your function isn't adding anything to the page.

we use `appendChild` to add a node to the page.

In your function you create and add text to a div, but you don't return the node you made(*and also you didn't close your line of code with a semi-colon so I added that too*) but this should work:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Media Player
  </title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="my-player">
    Hello!
  </div>

  <script>
    function makeOscarPlayer() {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = `hello`;
      return div;
    }
    document.getElementById("my-video").appendChild(makeOscarPlayer())
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
    function makeOscarPlayer() {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = `hello`;
      return div;
    }
    document.getElementById("my-video").appendChild(makeOscarPlayer())
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Media Player
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- added my-video div -->
  <div id="my-video"></div>

  <div class="my-player">
    Hello!
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```