# How to add some new content at a button click event on javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, appendchild, insertafter

I'm new at programming so I may have made some, even obvious mistakes.

Now I'm working on a little script where I'd like to add some new content in a paragraph after a div I made at 2 conditions ( if, else ).

if something is written than put the text into a div and the console.

else create a `<p>` element and write that text is needed after the div element.

I set the code but the console on Chrome says that

```
DivI.insertAfter(p, Div) is not a function
```

at onclick(HTML) property inside the button.

Even `DivT.appendChild(text)` is not a function.

Following the guide given by Brackets, I, inside the if,
created a new variable DivT and appended the text(createTextNode) inside DivT.

Inside the else I created a new element `<p>`, inserted text inside, created 2 variables in order to use the method `insertAfter` as it was written on the guide.

One for telling where to append and the other to tell after which element putting the `<p>` element.

I can't make it work.

Here is the code.

HTML

```
           <input type="text" id="scrivimi">

           <button type="button" onloadend="Cliccando()" 
           onclick="Cliccando()">
            Clicca 
           </button>

    <div id="Div"></div>
```

Apart from a title these are the only elements in the page.

Javascript

```
        function Cliccando() {
          var testo2 = document.getElementById('scrivimi').value;
            if ( testo2 != '')
                {
                    alert('js qualcosa scritto');
                    console.log(testo2);
                    var DivT = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                    var DelTesto = document.createTextNode(testo2);
                    DivT.appendChild(DelTesto);
                   }
                else {
                      alert (' js vuoto');
                      var p = document.createElement("p");
                      var Contenuto = document.createTextNode('Scrivi del testo');
                p.appendChild(Contenuto);
                var DivI= document.getElementById('Div');
                var Div = document.getElementById('Div');
                DivI.insertAfter(p, Div);

            }

     }
```

Comment: JS has an `insertBefore` but not an `insertAfter`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4793604/1810460) for a workaround

Comment: I would  create div in html and provide display - block or none on JavaScript function as per needed.

Comment: Also, the reason you're getting an error with `appendChild` is that [`getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) not just a single Node. I would recommend instead using `getElementById`

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!