# How to place div clone right under original div?

Tags: javascript, html, duplicates, clone

I currently have an "Add more" button that when clicked, duplicates a div I have. The problem currently is when the button is clicked and the div duplicates, it appears below the "Add more" button. I want the div to duplicate right under the original div when clicked, this also means the duplicate will be above the "Add more" button. How do I go about doing this?

HTML

```
                    <!-- Instrument Exp. -->
                    <div>
                        <label>What instruments and level do you want to teach?</label>
                        <div class="form-inline justify-content-center" id="ins_1">
                            <!-- Instrument 1 -->
                            <div>
                                <select class="form-control ins">
                                    <option>Instrument</option>
                                    <option>Cello</option>
                                    <option>Clarinet</option>
                                    <option>Drums</option>
                                    <option>Flute</option>
                                    <option>Guitar</option>
                                    <option>Piano</option>
                                    <option>Saxophone</option>
                                    <option>Violin</option>
                                    <option>Vocal</option>
                                    <option>Trumpet</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Level 1 -->
                            <div>
                                <select class="form-control lvl">
                                    <option>Level</option>
                                    <option>Beginner</option>
                                    <option>Advanced</option>
                                    <option>Intermediate</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    <!-- Add More -->
                    <div class="text-center" id="add_more">
                        <button type="button" class="no_link" onclick="add_instrument()">Add more +</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript

```
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('ins_1');

function add_instrument() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "ins_1" + ++i;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

See insertBefore, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore. If you combine it with nextSibling, you can have it add right after it:

```
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('ins_1');
function add_instrument() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "ins_1" + ++i;
    original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, original.nextSibling);
}
```

Also see: [How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

**Edit**: As @Tej pointed out in the comments, there are nice functions to insert nodes adjacently: [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), and [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement). `insertAdjacentElement` requires IE8+ or a recent browser.

The code becomes more readable with those functions, in my opinion:

```
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('ins_1');
function add_instrument() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "ins_1" + ++i;
    original.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', clone);
}
```

Comment: I think we can try insertAdjacentHTML as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: This will always insert after the first element in the list rather than appending to the end of the list

Comment: @GarrettJohnson, I believe this is the behavior the questioner wanted: "I want the div to duplicate right under the original div when clicked"

Comment: @Tej, nice! I didn't know about those methods. It looks like `insertAdjacentElement` might be the one to go with.

Comment: Oh, I suppose that could be true. I hadn't read it that way. That will result in the list of items being ordered in 1, 5, 4, 3, 2 if multiple adds happen.

Comment: @Steve Sorry I pasted the wrong URL. Here is the right one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement

Answer (score 1):

`appendChild` inserts the node as the last child of the node. In this case, that's after the 'add more' button because your list and button are children within the same element.

#### Solution 1

Put your list of new instruments in a different element so appending to the end of the parent has the desired effect.

```
<div>
    <label>What instruments and level do you want to teach?</label>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="form-inline justify-content-center" id="ins_1">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add More -->
    <div class="text-center" id="add_more">
        <button type="button" class="no_link" onclick="add_instrument()">Add more +</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Solution 2

Use insert before and insert before the "add more button".

```
original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, addMoreButton);
```

#### Solution 3 (not recommended)

Append the "add more" button appending the new instrument item to place it back at the end of the list.