# how to append an inline element using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, inline

I want to append a span element after an input field but appending the span to the input field using `appendChild()`is not working as I'd like. How can I append an inline element after another element in js?

Here's my code to create the span element

```
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.setAttribute("id", inputNameValues[i] + "-error");
    var errorText = document.createTextNode("* " + inputLabels[i] + " must not be left blank");
    span.appendChild(errorText);
    input.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're appending span as a child of input, rather than as a sibling.

I think you might be better using Element.insertAdjacentHTML() instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: I am getting this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertAdjacentHTML' on 'Element': The element has no parent. My input tags are inside a form which is inside a fieldset, how can it not have a parent node?

Comment: I've copied it into codepen and having a look

Comment: Are you definitely defining input as a variable somewhere? I'm getting that as an error in codepen.

Comment: I have realised the problem, I am creating all the HTML dynamically and was trying to reference parentNode before I'd actually appended its parent to the DOM. Ooops... thanks for the assistance