# Is any way to select `<body>` tag? Working with `getElementById("bodyTagId")` but not working with `getElementsByTagName("body")`

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am developing support chat website, i want to append response of ajax html to after body tag's inner html.

e.g.: append html after h2 tag(here is html of web page.)

```js
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {                                                           
     referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode,referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var el = document.createElement("span");
el.innerHTML = "<p>test</p>";
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
insertAfter(div, el);
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <title>script example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2>here is html of web page.</h2>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

Comment: it showing `Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined`, dude @codyKL

Comment: Means the element where you want to use this function doesn't exists.
Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/yn2awrxp/1/

Comment: Working with `document.getElementById("bodyTagId")` but not working with `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` i used this script for multiple site so it is not possible for all site have unique id of body tag.
is any way to select `<body>` tag 
Thankyou for your response.

Comment: try document.body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName` will return an array. So you have to take the first element of the array to get the actual body tag. Something like below

```
var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
bodyTag[0].append(...);
```

Comment: Thank you, i understood when i select element by `document.getElementsByTagName` it returns array and `document.getElementById` returns object.  :)