# How to create a div in Javascript and position it in the middle of the html template

Tags: javascript, html, json, position

I am currently trying to get some data from an online json element generator, which generates random users data. I want to manipulate this data and put it in the middle of my "contacts" page.

Everything is going well, the only problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to put this div, which I creat in JS, in the middle of my page, as it appears always after the footer. I already tried to create a div in the html template and in the JS append a child to this div, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

```js
getResultado();


function getResultado() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
        for (var i =0; i<json.results.length; i++) {
            console.log(json.results[i]);
            obj = json.results[i];
            document.body.appendChild(contactos(obj));
        }
    });
}
let jsonDiv = document.getElementById("json");
function contactos(info){
    let contactosElement = document.createElement("div");
    contactosElement.classList.add("contactos");

    let contactoElement = document.createElement("div");
    contactoElement.classList.add("contacto");

    let tituloElement = document.createElement("h3");
    tituloElement.innerText = "Geral";

    let nomeElement = document.createElement("p");
    nomeElement.innerText = info.name.first;

    let mailElement = document.createElement("p");
    mailElement.innerText = info.email;


    jsonDiv.appendChild(contactosElement);

    contactosElement.appendChild(contactoElement);
    contactoElement.appendChild(tituloElement);
    contactoElement.appendChild(nomeElement);
    contactoElement.appendChild(mailElement);

    return contactosElement;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fahkwang&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contactos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/contactos.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo"><a href="home.html"><img width="100" height="100" src="imagens/qf.png" alt="logo"></a></div>
        <div class="barras" onclick="anim(this); abrir()">
            <div id="barra1"></div>
            <div id="barra2"></div>
            <div id="barra3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="cartaz.html">CARTAZ</a>
            <a href="historia.html">HISTÓRIA</a>
            <a href="contactos.html">VOLUNTARIA-TE</a><a
                href="loja.html">LOJA</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="titulo"><h1>Voluntaria-te</h1></div>
    <form>
        <label for="pnome" class="titulo">Primeiro Nome</label>
        <input type="text" id="pnome" name="pnome" placeholder="O seu primeiro nome...">

        <label for="unome" class="titulo">Apelido</label>
        <input type="text" id="unome" name="unome" placeholder="O seu ultimo nome...">

        <label for="telemovel" class="titulo">Telemóvel:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="telemovel" name="usuario_telemovel" placeholder="O seu número de telemóvel...">

        <label for="profissão" class="titulo">Profissão:</label>
        <input type="text" id="profissão" name="usuario_profissão" placeholder="A sua profissão...">

        <label for="país" class="titulo">País de Nascimento</label>
        <select id="país" name="país">
            <option value="portugal">Portugal</option>
            <option value="espanha">Espanha</option>
            <option value="frança">França</option>
        </select>

        <label for="data" class="titulo">Data de Nascimento</label>
        <input type="date" id="data" name="data">

        <label for="carta" class="titulo">Carta de Motivação:</label>
        <textarea id="carta" placeholder="Qual a importância desta experiência para si?"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Submeter">
    </form>


    <div id="json"></div>

</main>
<footer>
    <div id="redes">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/queimadasfitascoimbra/" target="_blank"><img width="40" height="40"
                                                                                       src="imagens/fb.png"
                                                                                       alt="fb"></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/queimadasfitascoimbra/" target="_blank"><img width="40" height="40"
                                                                                        src="imagens/insta.png"
                                                                                        alt="insta"></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/queimacoimbra" target="_blank"><img width="40" height="40" src="imagens/tt.png"
                                                                         alt="tt"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <address>
            E-mail: queimadasfitascoimbra.pt <br>
            Morada:Rua Padre António Vieira, 1 3000-315 Coimbra <br>
        </address>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="JS/json.js"></script>
<script src="JS/menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your approach with appending a child to another div is very close to a working solution. Using e.g. jQuery you can use `insertAfter` to accomplish it with minimal code: https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Comment: the problem is that i can only use pure js :/

Comment: Why? Just insert jQuery CDN into your template as script tag and you are good to go.

Comment: it´s for a university work, jquery is not allowed

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're doing:

```js
document.body.appendChild(contactos(obj));
```

This will literally append a new child to the end of the `body` element. Since your footer is already at the end of `body`, your new elements will come after the footer.

What you should really do is create a unique container on your page before the footer and give it an ID, say `contacts`, and append to *that* element:

```html
<body>
  <header>Your header stuff here</header>
  <main>
    ...
    <!-- Append to this -->
    <section id="contacts"></section>
    ...
  </main>
  <footer>This is your footer</footer>
</body>
```

```js
// outside the loop
const contacts = document.getElementById('contacts');
...
// in your loop
contacts.appendChild(contactos(obj));
```

But it seems you already have such a placeholder div with an ID of `json`. The issue remains, however, since you then do `document.body.appendChild(contactos(obj))`, and that effectively puts everything at the end of the body.

I would approach the problem like this:

1. The `contactos` function should only worry about returning your `contactos` element. I would actually avoid naming these two the same thing, as that gets a little confusing. Maybe call the element `contactosElement`.
2. Get a reference to the `json` div.
3. Append the result of #1 to the `json` div in your loop, instead of doing `document.body.appendChild(contactos(obj))`.

Comment: I am sorry, i think that´s exactly what i did, i created a div called "json" in my html, then, in the js i wrote: 
let json = document.getElementById("json");
    json.appendChild(contactos); 
isn´t it, what you are saying?

Comment: Edited to clarify the issue. You're right that you have a `json` div. However, you are still ultimately appending the result of the `contactos` function to the body.

Comment: Sorry, in fact i was naming the contactosElement as contactos, which is the same name as in the function, i already changed it to contactos element. Then, i inserted my let json=document.getElementByID outside the loop as you sugested but it didnt work. but there is one thing i dont understand in your reply, which is the fact that i am not doing this: "document.body.appendChild(contactos(obj))"  i am actualy doing this: " contactos.appendChild(contacto);"

Comment: i actually don´t even know where did you find this: "document.body.appendChild(contactos(obj))."

Comment: It's in `getResultado`.

Comment: (Anyway i edited it to the new version, where the elements are named properly and the let json declaration is outside the loop

Comment: OOOOOOH, now i understood, i used this piece of code from a Exercise i did in the classes, i would never find it, let me see if it solves it