# Finding and Inserting Item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'd like to check every attribute src of the image that has class `.sogreen` that has a unique prefix on the start of the name or anywhere in the name. After that, it will find the `img` element that has a `title` attribute that has the same prefix on the first image that we get, and then insert that image below the first image.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="original">
  <img src="pref1-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="pref99-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="pref44-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>

<div class="image-entry-to-insert">
  <img src="test12.png" title="pref1" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="test4.png" title="pref99" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="test54.png" title="pref44" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>
```

**Result Should be**:

```html
<div class="original">
  <img src="pref1-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <!-- Inserted Item -->
  <img src="test12.png" title="pref1" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <!-- End of Inserted Item -->
  <img src="pref99-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <!-- Inserted Item -->
  <img src="test4.png" title="pref99" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <!-- End of Inserted Item -->
  <img src="pref44-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <!-- Inserted Item -->
  <img src="test54.png" title="pref44" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <!-- End of Inserted Item -->
</div>
```

**Rough JS Not working**:

```js
var imgsrc = $("img.sogreen").attr('src');
console.log(imgsrc);
$(imgsrc).each(function(index, value) {
  var imgData = $(this);
  $("img").each(function(index2, value2) {
    var elementTocounter = $(this).attr('title');
    if (imgData == elementTocounter) {
      // TODO img insertafter so green
    }
  });
});
```

**Note:** sogreen image might change continuously so for example if the sogreen change the src for an instance the below image should be updated as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this in vanilla JS:

```js
// get original images
let origImages = document.querySelectorAll(".original .sogreen")

// loop through originals
origImages.forEach((orig) => {
    // get prefix
    let prefix = orig.attributes.src.value.split("-")[0]

    // get element to be inserted
    let insert = document.querySelector(`[title='${prefix}'].sogreen`)

    // insert element as sibling
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793630/1366033
    orig.parentNode.insertBefore(insert, orig.nextSibling);
})
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
// get original images
let origImages = document.querySelectorAll(".original .sogreen")

// loop through originals
origImages.forEach((orig) => {
    // get prefix
    let prefix = orig.attributes.src.value.split("-")[0]

    // get element to be inserted
    let insert = document.querySelector(`[title='${prefix}'].sogreen`)

    // insert element as sibling
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793630/1366033
    orig.parentNode.insertBefore(insert, orig.nextSibling);
})
```

```html
<div class="original">
  <img src="pref1-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="pref99-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="pref44-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>

<div class="image-entry-to-insert">
  <img src="test12.png" title="pref1" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="test4.png" title="pref99" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="test54.png" title="pref44" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following uses `filter()` to find the associated opposite image and `after()` to insert

```js
// demo setup only
$('img').attr('alt', function(){ return $(this).attr('src')});


let $origImg = $('.original img.sogreen'),
    $insImg = $('.image-entry-to-insert img.sogreen')
    
    
$insImg.each(function(){
    const prefix = this.title;
    
    $origImg.filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('src').startsWith(prefix)
    }).after(this)

})
```

```css
img{display:block; margin:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="original">
<p>Original</p>
  <img src="pref1-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="pref99-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="pref44-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="image-entry-to-insert">
<p>to insert</p>
<img src="test12.png" title="pref1" class="img-responsive sogreen">
<img src="test4.png" title="pref99" class="img-responsive sogreen">
<img src="test54.png" title="pref44" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.after(function)` jQuery method like so:

```
$('div.original > img[src].sogreen').after(function() {
    let prefix = $(this).attr('src').split('-')[0];
    return $('div.image-entry-to-insert > img[title].sogreen')
        .filter((i,img) => $(img).attr('title') === prefix);
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
    $('div.original > img[src].sogreen').after(function() {
        let prefix = $(this).attr('src').split('-')[0];
        return $('div.image-entry-to-insert > img[title].sogreen')
            .filter((i,img) => $(img).attr('title') === prefix);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="original">
  <img src="pref1-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="pref99-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="pref44-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>

<div class="image-entry-to-insert">
  <img src="test12.png" title="pref1" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="test4.png" title="pref99" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="test54.png" title="pref44" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! @PeterKA how ever its not working if the url is already included

Comment: @LuvyGimeno would you please explain what you mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for your issue using JQuery as @KyleMit already posted a JS Vanilla perfect answer.

```js
var origImages = $(".original .sogreen");


$.each(origImages, function(key, value) {
  var prefix = $(value).attr('src').split('-')[1];
  var toI = $('.image-entry-to-insert [title=' + prefix + ']');
  toI.insertAfter($(value));
})
```

```css
.original {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="original">
  <img src="image/full/path/img-pref1-awesome.png" alt="pref1-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="image/full/path/img-pref99-awesome.png" alt="pref99-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="image/full/path/img-pref44-awesome.png" alt="pref44-awesome.png" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>

<div class="image-entry-to-insert">
  <img src="test12.png" alt="test12.png" title="pref1" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="test4.png" alt="test4.png" title="pref99" class="img-responsive sogreen">
  <img src="test54.png" alt="test54.png" title="pref44" class="img-responsive sogreen">
</div>
```

---- UPDATE ----

I have changed the snippet scenario so that the `pref#` part of the `src` attribute is not at the beginning of the String but at another position (in this case the second).

In this scenario we change the line `var prefix = $(value).attr('src').split('-')[0];` to `var prefix = $(value).attr('src').split('-')[1];` of the JavaScript code so instead of getting the first position when splitting the String, we get the second where the `pref#` part is located.

What you need to make sure is that when you standarize the `url` of the `src` attribute you do it in such a way that when splitting by a specific character the `pref#` part will always occupy the same position, i.e. [1] in our case.

Comment: Thank you! @nicholas but it's not working if the url are already included :(

Comment: @LuvyGimeno Which url you mean? If you mean that the `src="pref99-awesome.png"`changes to lets say `src="sometinngelseinhere-pref99-awesome.png"` just make sure that instead of getting the `[0]` element in the split array you get the desired one. I'm editing the post to include this.