# Overriding Quill.js optimisation process to enable having two consequtive tags separately (not joined)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rich-text-editor, quill, devextreme

### Hello,

I am in desperate necessity of having two consequtive tags next to each other in Quill Rich Text editor like this:

```html
<p>Dummy: <em>One italic format,</em><em> and another italic format.</em> dummy</p>
```

What I'm getting in Quill is:

```html
<p>Dummy: <em>One italic format, and another italic format.</em> dummy</p>
```

I am trying to override natural behavior of Quill.js library, as in [official documentation](https://quilljs.com/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment#adding-quill-core) situation is stated really clear:

> Since `<p><span>Text</span></p>` and `<p>Text</p>` represent the same content, the former is invalid and it is part of Quill’s optimization process to unwrap the `<span>`. Similarly, once we add formatting, `<p><em>Te</em><em>st</em></p>` and `<p><em><em>Test</em></em></p>` are also invalid, as they are not the most compact representation.
>
> Because of these constraints, Quill cannot support arbitrary DOM trees and HTML changes. But as we will see, the consistency and predicability this structure provides enables us to easily build rich editing experiences.

#### What I've tried:

Mainly I tried extending italic blot `create()` function in with following ideas:

- appending html attributes to italic node to diffrentiate two tags (unsuccessfull, Quill still joins them):

```js
import Quill from "quill";

const OriginalItalic = Quill.import("formats/italic");

export class MyItalic extends OriginalItalic {
  static create(){

    const node = super.create();

    // some not related code here
    node.setAttribute("title", `Italic number: #${previouslySetNumberHere}`);
    // more unrelated logic here

    return node;
  }
}
Quill.register("formats/italic", MyItalic, true);
```

- using [DOM manipulation techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib) to insert text node with [zero-width-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) after each italic.
  However `create()` function does not append it directly to Quill tree. All it does is return the inserted node, so that it's not yet attached during function execution. Therefore i can't insert after non-existing-node. I've abbandonded this idea due to this reasoning.
- changing italic `tagName` property to diffrent, supported HTML tags in hope Quill will solve my problems, I've tried `<q>`, `<cite>`, `<u>`, `<pre>` (this one behaves quite diffrently due to being block-blot not inline-blot, [(info)](https://quilljs.com/docs/formats#inline)), and others. With same unsuccessful result (Quill joining them).

#### Related info:

I do not need to use ItalicBlot. I can use diffrent one, as long as it's not font color, background color or font I will apply my own styling anyway. I realised Quill doesn't snap together two `<span>`s with diffrent colors.

#### Possibly related info:

I am using Vue.js with DevExtreme. My Rich text editor is Devextreme widget however it is driven by Quill, and I have successfully extended other things in my project with this approach (Quill directly, not widget itself - however I've done this too)

Comment: did you got any solution for these

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to extend from the Inline Blot rather than the format and leave the implementation of the `optimize` method empty. Something like this:

```
const Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline')

class ItalicBlot extends Inline {
    static create() {
        return super.create()
    }
    static formats() {
        return true
    }
    optimize(context) {}
}
ItalicBlot.blotName = 'italic'
ItalicBlot.tagName = ['EM', 'I']

Quill.register(ItalicBlot, true);
```

It could be an approach. You can read more about blots in the [guide on their website](https://quilljs.com/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment/).