# How to get tag name of the element clicked

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, appendchild

i need to add element to parent of click tag

> note:tag have not class or id
> **add button to li tag**

```
 <ul >
    <li >
      <textarea >title</textarea>
        <a href="#" onclick=add_input(?)>tt</a>
    </li>  
 </ul>

    function add_input(?) {
        var btn = document.createElement("input"); 
        btn .setAttribute('type', "submit");
        btn .setAttribute('value', "Submit");
       ???.appendChild(btn);
    }
```

how to complete code where ? and ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

Comment: it is use id of element, is it  possible  with out id of element

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```js
function add_input(element) {
    var btn = document.createElement("input"); 
    btn.setAttribute('type', "submit");
    btn.setAttribute('value', "Submit");
    element.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li >
      <textarea >title</textarea>
        <a href="#" onclick=add_input(this)>tt</a>
    </li>  
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> it is work for me ?==>event ???==>
> e.target.parentElement.appendChild(btn)

```js
function add_input(e) {
        var btn = document.createElement("input"); 
        btn.setAttribute('type', "submit");
        btn.setAttribute('value', "Submit");
        e.target.parentElement.appendChild(btn)
    }
```

```html
      <ul>
        <li >
              <textarea >title</textarea>
            <a href="#" onclick=add_input(event)>tt</a>
        </li>  
     </ul>
```