# AppendChild between paragraphs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using `appendChild` to insert an iframe between paragraphs dynamically.
The problem is that (for some reason) the iframe is being inserted BEFORE the `</p>` and not AFTER, as I need.

My original HTML:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); // array of paragraphs
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe"); // create iframe
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://example.com"); // set iframe URL
elements[2].appendChild(ifrm); // insert iframe
```

What I get:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text <iframe src="..."></iframe> </p>
<p>Some text</p>
```

What I expect to get:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p> <iframe src="..."></iframe>
<p>Some text</p>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot have a block-level element like `<iframe>` inside a `<p>`. A `<p>` block can only contain running text and text-like elements.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib.

You need to insert it AFTER the <p>, (so it becomes a sibling, not a child)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elements[2].parentNode.insertBefore(ifrm, elements[3])`

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); // array of paragraphs
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe"); // create iframe
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://example.com"); // set iframe URL
elements[2].parentNode.insertBefore(ifrm, elements[3]);
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
```