# JavaScript : How to add iframe after every paragraph?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and expect a answer from expert.

Suppose following is my piece of content -

```html
<p> This is the first paragraph </p>
<p> This is the second paragraph </p>
```

and, I want to add few block of code after every paragraph and code became following -

```html
<p> This is the first paragraph </p>
<figure class="x">
  <iframe width="300" height="250" style="border:0; margin:0;" src="#">
  </iframe>
</figure>
<p> This is the second paragraph </p>
<figure class="x">
  <iframe width="300" height="250" style="border:0; margin:0;" src="#">
  </iframe>
</figure>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will do research and and ask questions next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this javascript to get started.

```
// get all "p" tags
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // create figure
    const figure = document.createElement("figure");
    figure.className = "x";
    // create iframe
    const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "300");
    iframe.setAttribute("height", "250");
    iframe.setAttribute("href", "#");
    iframe.style.border = 0;
    iframe.style.margin = 0;
    figure.appendChild(iframe);
    // append to "p" tag
    elements[i].parentNode.insertBefore(figure, elements[i].nextSibling);
}​
```

Comment: OP want `figure` after every `p` not child of `p`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `figure` HTML element that has a child `iframe` and then add the `figure` element after every `p`

[How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

```js
const paras = document.querySelectorAll("p");

function createIframe(width, height, style, src) {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.setAttribute("width", width);
  iframe.setAttribute("height", height);
  iframe.setAttribute("style", style);
  iframe.setAttribute("src", src);

  return iframe;
}

function createFigureElement() {
  const figure = document.createElement("figure");
  figure.classList.add("x");

  figure.appendChild(createIframe("300", "250", "border:0; margin:0;", "#"));
  return figure;
}

function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
paras.forEach((p) => {
  insertAfter(p, createFigureElement());
});
```

```html
<p> This is the first paragraph </p>
<p> This is the second paragraph </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the shortest way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => {
    p.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', 
        `<figure class="x">
             <iframe width="300" height="250" style="border:0; margin:0;" src="#"></iframe>
        </figure>`
    );
})
```

```html
<p> This is the first paragraph </p>
<p> This is the second paragraph </p>
```