# why dont work insertAfter function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
 but insertbefore work

var a=document.querySelector("#div");

var y=document.createElement('p');
y.innerText='yazilarucun';


var c=document.querySelector(".p");
a.insertAfter(y,c);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='div'>yazi
  <p class='p'>p etiketi</p>
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Take a look: [How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793630/7750416

Answer (score 1):

The node.insertAfter() is not an inbuilt javascript method, instead we created a user-defined function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="point">Start</p>

<script>
var parentNode = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var refNode = document.getElementById("point");

function insertAfter(newNode, refNode){
 refNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, refNode.nextSibling);
}

var newNode = document.createElement("p"); 
var textnode = document.createTextNode("End");
newNode.appendChild(textnode);
insertAfter(newNode, refNode);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

check : https://www.wikimass.com/js/node-insertafter

Comment: sry i was to late =D

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem Can be fixed pretty easily. You can fix this by adding the node before the node that is after the the node

```js
function insertAfter(newNode, existingNode) {
  existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
}
//Create Element
var new_para = document.createElement('p');
new_para.innerText = 'yazilarucun';
//Add the element
var old_para = document.querySelector(".p");
insertAfter(new_para, old_para)
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='div'>yazi
    <p class='p'>p etiketi</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is at least 3 ways to do it.

```
let targetNode = document.querySelector('#wrapper'),
    placeNode = document.querySelector('#footer');

targetNode.after(placeNode);
targetNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', placeNode);
targetNode.parentNode.insertBefore(placeNode, targetNode.nextSibling);
```

The first of these 3, is the newest and simplest. Has been supported since Chrome 54+, Firefox 49+, Edge 17+. No IE support...

Last one is best support, oldest and most complicated one...

Middle one is somewhere in the middle... Is still too hard... Not intuitive enough...