# Angular add dom element after current input in directive

Tags: html, angular, dom, element, directive

I have two inputs:

```html
      <label for="date-string">String value</label>
      <input [formControl]="dateString" type="date" id="date-string"/>
      <br>
      <label for="date-object">Date object with directive help</label>
      <input [formControl]="dateObject" type="date" id="date-object"/>
```

I want to add a div straight after an input using a directive for all inputs type 'date' and have 'formControl' directive.

The only problème is how to add a dom element after current html element (using elementRef).
I've seen ppl talking about parent node, but i don't want to appendChild to the parent node (the new element will be at the very end of the node list but i need it to be straight after current input element).

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can break this down into two questions:

**Q1:** How to apply a directive to all `input` elements with `type="date"` and with the attribute `formControl`?

**A1:** When declaring a directive you can use any CSS selector to choose which elements the directive is applied to: https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#options

**Q2:** How to insert a div immediately after another element?

**A2:** Use `insertBefore` applied to the element's next sibling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793630/12914833

So the directive looks like this:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type="date"][formControl]',
})
export class DateInputDirective {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
    const el = elRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = 'Inserted Div';
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    // any other styling
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(div, el.nextSibling);
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n4ault?file=src/app/date-input.directive.ts

Answer (score -1):

```
  <div *mydirective>
      <label for="date-string">String value</label>
      <input [formControl]="dateString" type="date" id="date-string"/>
  </div>
  <br>
  <label for="date-object">Date object with directive help</label>
  <input [formControl]="dateObject" type="date" id="date-object"/>
```

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
@Directive({
  selector: '[mydirective']
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const child = this.document.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, child);
  }
}
```

So with css/sass techniques to can set the appropriate position for your new element

Comment: your solution need more contribution from his side like changing the HTML structure which is not what he need for exsisting project -> i belive he should make an directive with and it is selecter should target all inputs with type date shomthing like input[type=date] and getting the elementRef nativeElemnt then parent node and using insertBefore or insertAfter to append the div without doing anychnage to the current HTML