# Insert text after specific line in string with multiple lines (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string with multiple lines in JavaScript.
How can I insert another string after a specific line, so for example line 2?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy solutions can be to use plugin that creates lines for you. Remember that when user changes screen size and your div size changes - lines will be not the same. https://splitting.js.org/

Here is example how to insert element after element in pure javascript [How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert the whole string into an array based on the line break and then insert the text you want by using [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method and then join again to get the string with multiple lines.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const str = 'abc<br>def<br>ghi<br>jkl';

const splittedStr = str.split('<br>');

splittedStr.splice(1, 0, 'alpha');

const finalStr = splittedStr.join('<br>');

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = finalStr;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```